# Can't see the script panel on Google Earth Engine

Tags: google-earth-engine

I'm trying to figure out why I cannot see the script panel on [gee platform](https://code.earthengine.google.com) but there is almost nothing on the web! Even the Google group is private.

Answer (score 1):

Did you maybe move the bottom bar of the panel all the way up? Check the middle part at the top, if it looks anything like the picture below, just place your cursor there and drag it down [image: hidden panel link]

Comment: I have finally found the panel in the very left side of the view, it was difficult to see the dragging bar because of part of the windows was outside the view.